# Cannot Forward Port 22 to Local Machine

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding

Cross-Posted from askubuntu on the recommendation of a user there. I am having trouble setting up my server running Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed openssh, set up my router to forward port 22 to the server's local IP address, and can even ssh correctly when on my local network and using the server's local IP. ex using:

```
ssh user@local.ip.address
```

However, when I leave the network and try

```
ssh user@public.ip.address
```

nothing happens. I cannot get port 22 to show up as open using https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

On my router settings, I have port 22 forwarded to local address port 22. I also have my router (WAN_IN and WAN_LOCAL) and server firewalls set up to allow port 22 through. Something interesting is that if I forward port 2222 to local address port 22, I can ssh into the router command line interface, but otherwise I cannot.

One thing that seems inconsistent is that my local IP address is x.x.2.x while my router IP address subnet is x.x.0.x. Could this be the source of the problem? And if so, what do I need to do?

For reference, I have an EdgeRouter with Ubiquiti.

Comment: Are you behind your ISPs NAT?  (How you can tell is your public ip address will report as an intranet ip address subnet).  "x.x.0.x" - doesn't tell me anything, if you have a NAT address, it is harmless to share it.  Even if you have a public address share more then a single digit.

Comment: I suggest you run WireShark (in the repository) to monitor the local logins and the failed remote logins and see where the handshakes diverge.

Comment: I didn't include the local addresses just for clarity. They are 192.168.2.103 and 192.168.0.1 respectively